# How to convert y%m%d%H format into "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S" in time series data

Tags: r, time-series

How do I convert the `y%m%d%H` format into `"%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"`. My dates run from 1970 to 2010.

Comment: date <- strptime(Z$V1,format = "%y%m%d%H",tz = "GMT")

Comment: What you suggested above seems to work for me: as a tiny example (hint, see http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000): `strptime("2012 5 10 13",format="%Y %m %d %H")` gives `[1] "2012-05-10 13:00:00"`

Comment: %Y%m%d%H  with this format it works but format is %y%m%d%H example 00010100(2000010100)

Answer (score 6):

Going partly from the comments (it would be nice if you could modify the question accordingly), it seems that this is not a case of formatting (`%y` vs `%Y` or spacing/delimiters), but of `strptime`/`POSIX*t` automatically setting the format to skip the hours/minutes/seconds when a 'midnight' time is specified.  (This is my current guess based on the following examples, but I could have missed something.)

with `%y`, with non-midnight time:

```
> str(strptime("00020304",format="%y%m%d%H"))
 POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2000-02-03 04:00:00"
```

ditto, midnight time:

```
> str(strptime("00020300",format="%y%m%d%H"))
 POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2000-02-03"
```

midnight time (with spaces)

```
> str(strptime("00 02 03 00",format="%y %m %d %H"))
 POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2000-02-03"
```

a vector with one midnight and one non-midnight time:

```
> str(strptime(c("00020300","00020304"),format="%y%m%d%H"))
 POSIXlt[1:2], format: "2000-02-03 00:00:00" "2000-02-03 04:00:00"
```

So it looks like Dirk's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
R> Sys.Date()
[1] "2012-07-23"
R> format(Sys.Date())
[1] "2012-07-23"
R> format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2012-07-23 00:00:00"
R>
```

as you probably have a `Date` type which, by definition, has no hour/minute/second information--use `POSIXct` for that. See `help(DateTimeClasses)` the details, and a bazillion posts here and on the various mailing lists with working examples.

Comment: %Y%m%d%H with this format it works but format is %y%m%d%H example 00010100(2000010100)

Comment: Based on my tests below it's not quite that the OP has a `Date` type, but rather than `POSIX*t` seems to set the format to skip H/M/S when it has a date at a midnight time.

Comment: That is possible too, but as he never told us via a reproducible example, we cannot really tell, can we?

Comment: There are examples in the comments (if that counts).  To the OP's credit (although it's not a well-written question), the fact that (it seems) `POSIX*t` sets a different format for vectors with all-midnight and some-non-midnight times is potentially confusing (and again IMHO) not a great default choice of behavior.