# How to convert the date format is %y%m%d to %Y%m%d in R

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert y%m%d%H format into “%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S” in time series data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614180/how-to-convert-ymdh-format-into-ymd-hms-in-time-series-data)

How to convert the date format is %y%m%d(000101=20000101) to %Y%m%d(20000101) in R dataframes(

Comment: In the future it would be nice if a clearer example was included, but you did include the starting values (000101) and what the results should look like.  Thanks for that :)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate I think -- just closely related.

Comment: @BenBolker. IMHO it's close enough to a dupe, that the OP should have edited the other question instead of creating a new one. -1

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! To avoid negative reactions like these to any future questions you may ask, I strongly recommend you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/324364) question on how to write a great question about R and make sure to follow its advice in the future.

Comment: @GSee yeah they are pretty darn close.

Answer (score 6):

It is fairly easy.  I am going to assume that currently, your dates are stored as strings, as in the variable `x`.

```
x <- "000101"
```

First you can convert this to a date class.  Once that is done, `R` stores the dates as days since the origin.  Meaning that it is really numeric underneath.  However, special printing and display methods, show a prettier output when printed than the underlying numbers.  Converting to a date and forcing printing by adding `()`:

```
(xd <- as.Date(x, format = "%y%m%d"))
[1] "2000-01-01"
```

Now if you want to display it some non-default way (such as %Y%m%d), you can just ask `R` to format it that way.

```
format(xd, "%Y%m%d")
[1] "20000101"
```

and if you wanted, you could save the results back into your data frame.

```
(myx <- format(xd, "%Y%m%d"))
[1] "20000101"
```

Note that the results will again be character (string) class, *not* a date class.  That means (among other things) that you can no longer add or subtract, etc.  For example:

```
xd + 10
[1] "2000-01-11"
xd - 10
[1] "1999-12-22"
```

but

```
myx - 10
Error in myx - 10 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: @BenBolker edited to show an example of what I meant.  Sorry for not being clearer.

Comment: I was just giving you a hard time about spelling. ("substract" for "subtract" is a very common mistake among non-native English speakers -- have never paid enough attention to know if it's specific to particular languages)

Comment: Whoops.  Fixed now.  A bit embarrassed to say I am a native English speaker (of some sort).

Comment: I figured. Anyway, I was just teasing (but a bit too telegraphically).

Comment: subtract: from latin ``sub-traere``, so the s should not be there. Sadly it is there in French and Spanish (but not in Italian or Portuguese). So annoying.